# If a functor is isomorphic to an exact functor, is it exact?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Suppose $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are abelian categories and we have two functors $F, G: \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ with $F$ exact. Suppose also that there is a natural isomorphism $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$. Is $G$ also exact? Do I need further hypothesis on $\alpha$?

Comment: Isomorphic functors have the same exactness properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is also exact. Exactness of $A \overset{f}{\to} B \overset{g}{\to} C$ (only the middle part) means that $\mathrm{im}(f) \cong \ker(g)$. Well, it is a specific map that needs to be an isomorphism, but to keep things simple let us just show that $\mathrm{im}(G(f)) \cong \ker(G(g))$. We have
$$ \mathrm{im}(G(f)) \overset{1}{\cong} \mathrm{im}(F(f)) \overset{2}{\cong} \ker(F(g)) \overset{3}{\cong} \ker(G(g)).$$
Here is a short explanation of the isomorphisms:

1. $G \cong F$
2. $F(A) \overset{F(f)}{\to} F(B) \overset{F(g)}{\to} F(C)$ is exact (as $F$ is exact)
3. $F \cong G$.

Some more details for $1$ and $3$: what we know is that $F(f) = \alpha_Y^{-1} \circ G(f) \circ \alpha_X$, and you need to show (using the definition of the image) that composing a map with isomorphisms induces an isomorphism of the images, i.e., $\mathrm{im}(G(f)) \cong \mathrm{im}(\alpha_Y^{-1} \circ G(f) \circ \alpha_X)$, and the same for kernels.

**Hint:** It might be easier to do it in two steps, i.e., try to show that $\mathrm{im}(h) \cong \mathrm{im}(h \circ \alpha)$ and that $\mathrm{im}(h') \cong \mathrm{im}(\beta \circ h')$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are isomorphisms and $h$ and $h'$ are any maps.